# How do I specify a controller function inside an HTML form action attribute in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to trigger a controller instead of a route in my HTML form. 
I can't seem to figure it out and a ton of googling has only returns answers for Laravel 4.

My form looks like this:

```html
<form action="{{ ExpunctionIntakeController@getIndex }}" method="POST">
  ....
  ....
</form>
```

But this doesn't work at all. I don't want to use routes because I want to return views rather than urls.

What's the proper way to inject a controller action into my HTML?

Comment: You can't call controller methods whenever and wherever you are. The only way to access them is by using the router, since that's his purpose. Still, I did not quite understand what you are trying to do, please add more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your action, you are using blade syntax. If you want to use blade syntax & the Form Helper, use the following;

```
{{  Form::open(['action'=>'ExpunctionIntakeController@getIndex', 'method' => 'post']) }}
```

If you aren't using the Form Helper;

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('ExpunctionIntakeController@getIndex') }}">
```